# Django CSS background image will not change

Tags: python, css, django, python-3.x, static

I have downloaded an HTML template, and I am trying to change the background image inside the css file.

The code in the css is:

```
background: url(../img/background.jpg)
```

However, when I change it to the image I want, the background on the website when I run the server remains the same. The image exists and is in the correct location. The filepath is correct as well.

This is the code in my settings.py file:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "products/static"),
)
```

Comment: Did you attempt to run 'python manage.py collectstatic'?

Answer (score 0):

Click right button of mouse in Chrome browser and choose "Inspect element", you can see Error message in "Console" window, if it is 403 error than you have to change rights to 644 (`chmod 644 background.jpg`) or change owner of the file (`chown www-data:www-data background.jpg`). If it is 404 error than change the path of the file in css code.